# What's wrong with a user posting different and independent answers to a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers

When I posted different answers to a question, some people seemed to frown upon it.

[Is $G/pG$ is a $p$-group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232526/is-g-pg-is-a-p-group)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with posting as separate answers, if the strategies taken in the different answers are "sufficiently different". Unfortunately, "sufficiently different" is somewhat subjective...

Comment: @J.M. I think the three answers to the linked question are very different in the strategies.

Comment: @MakotoKato : hence J.M. wrote 'Unfortunately, "sufficiently different" is somewhat subjective.' The people who voted/commented may disagree with you.

Comment: @WillieWong In that case, what's wrong with posting several answers which are not sufficiently different?

Comment: Like you were already informed: this is looked upon as "reputation farming", a way to game the system. Some people see it as the same as trying to get paid twice for doing the work once. Seriously though: the users already quite clearly explained their reasons to you in the comments. You seem to be just unwilling to listen and appear to be just shopping for second opinions...

Comment: @WillieWong Please define reputation farming and explain why it's wrong.

Comment: @Makoto: I quote: "Some people see it as the same as trying to get paid twice for doing the work once." Or, as Cameron Blue described for you: "Trying to get more reputation by posting several answers [to the same question]." I am starting to get the feeling of déjà vu about the shape this conversation is taking on.

Comment: @WillieWong I don't see why it's trying to get paid twice for doing the work once.
They are essentially different answers.

Comment: @Makoto: I refer you to [my earlier comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/whats-wrong-with-a-user-posting-different-and-independent-answers-to-a-question#comment23116_6525). I'll excuse myself from this conversation now unless you ask a question whose answer I haven't already provided.

Comment: @WillieWong Let me ask the same question I asked robjohn.
What about posting an answer to a question which someone else already answered? There is nothing wrong with doing so, as long as they are sufficiently different?

Comment: What exactly are "independent answers"?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker An answer which does not depend on other answers. For example, it is not an improvement of another answer.

Comment: I think I've posted more than one answer to the same question a few times.  No one's complained to me about it.

Comment: My experience has been the same as @MichaelHardy's. I wonder if part of the difference is that fewer people trust Makoto Kato's good faith.

Comment: @MJD Are you implying that there is a good reason for people not to trust my good faith?

Comment: @MakotoKato I am only implying that fewer people trust your good faith. Surely you were already aware of this.

Answer (score 16):

### Doctor, it hurts when I do this

You're getting some push-back for something you're doing on the site. The feedback from other members prompted you to ask this question, but even prior to that *the software itself* gave you a bit of resistance when you went to add that second (and third) answer:

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
>
> You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

Of course, it is *allowed* - there are times when it's very useful - but they're not common; generally, you do want to just edit your existing answer.

### If you want feedback on your actions, explain their purpose

Let's ignore the abstract question here. As robjohn and Bill have pointed out in their answers, there are occasions when multiple answers are useful, and (many more) occasions where you really just want one answer. But that's not what you asked. You linked to *your* multiple answers, and a cursory examination makes one thing blatantly obvious:

**You aren't making any effort to explain why one answer might be preferable to another.**

There are often multiple ways to solve a problem. One of the big advantages of the Stack Exchange system is that, when posted as separate answers, the most *generally useful* solution can be ranked higher by those reading than the rest. However, this falls apart when there is effectively no difference, or when the difference is subtle. So... Which is it? You must've had a *reason* for bothering to write multiple responses - yet you didn't bother to include that reasoning in the answers themselves. It's almost as though you expect others to do this for you...

### Asking - and answering - in good faith

Indeed, this meta question suffers from the same problem. Right before asking it, you posted this comment below one of your answers, in response to specific criticism of your answering strategy:

> @CameronBuie Maybe someone would down vote for a false proof. This is only an example. There are other confusing factors. As for your last comment, I didn't get any reps. Anyway, what's wrong with separate answers? – Makoto Kato

Uh, yeah, *maybe* that would happen. Is that what you hoped would happen? Being unsure of one or more of your proofs, you posted them separately so as to elicit specific critiques of each? **Then why not *say* that?** And when raising the discussion of a specific scenario here, one already under discussion elsewhere, why not summarize your already-stated rationale for doing what you're doing, rather than leaving folks to debate the general case? There's a time and a place for everything - but what you're really concerned with here is, *was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232526/is-g-pg-is-a-p-group) the right time and place for multiple answers?*

Frankly, I think you would garner a lot more sympathy - or at least *understanding* - if you were a bit more transparent as to your intent when you engage in activities that are *uncommon* on this site. Don't assume that others will assume good intentions on your part, and you may find they're a bit more likely to do just that in the future.

Comment: "You aren't making any effort to explain why one answer might be preferable to another."

Because that's irrelevant to the title question.
As the title shows, I took it for granted that the three answers are essentially different.
I also took it for granted that showing different approaches to a problem is a pedagogically good thing.

Comment: If you were also the one voting on them and questioning their separation, then your assumptions would suffice. However, not everyone shares those assumptions. When you encounter clear evidence that this is the case, it becomes necessary to mention them explicitly.

Comment: @Makoto: To reiterate what has been told here, and countless times before, you cannot expect to be using the site in your *own* way without upsetting people. The fact that people tell you that something is not usually done means that you should *probably* justify it, at least at first. Furthermore, it is sometimes good to try and understand the other side and not just claim that this is just their opinion and you can do whatever you want. The **main** thing about a community is that it is based on several people, and note the similarity between "*community*" and "*communication*".

Comment: @Asaf I agree that it would be helpful to give some hint as to the motivation for separating the answers. But I don't think it should be required. I have posted multiple answers occasionally as have many other users, and not always with such motivation (often it is "clear"). But I don't recall any of those answers being criticized like MK's. Nor do I recall even a single instance where those multiple answers raised any doubts in my mind that they were posted to farm rep. That's not to say that might never occur. Rather, I think we need to judge such matters on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Huh, this is actually a very level-headed answer. Why the downvotes?

Comment: If you read the answers, it's clear that they are based on different ideas. I don't think it's necessary to say so.

Comment: Way I see it, here's what Makoto seems to have trouble comprehending: if he wants to use the site in his own peculiar way, he ought to not be surprised that other users are reacting in their own peculiar ways to whatever he's producing...

Comment: @J.M. This is not "his own peculiar way". There are many users who have posted multiple answers (including experienced high-rep users). If you wish to object to this then please debate the general principles - not the actions of a specific user.

Comment: @Bill, oh I certainly have posted multiple answers in some questions myself, so no need to throw that particular rock at me. What I'm saying is, it would seem that the answers being "sufficiently different" was not sufficiently justified from the viewpoint of whoever voted his answers. So, he shouldn't be so surprised. I mean, people actually had the courtesy to explain why they did what they did with respect to votes; that maybe is something to be stunned about.

Comment: @J.M. Browsing other multiple answers, I don't see *any* where the author has justified them. Do you know of any?

Comment: @Bill: regardless of how *other* instances have been received, it's indisputable that *this* case produced an unacceptable amount of confusion - both on the part of the asker, and the other readers. No matter how acceptable a technique might be *in theory*, when it doesn't work in practice it's time to revisit your assumptions.

Comment: @Shog9 That's only because of the OP's recent history. Had it been any other author, probably we would not be having this meta discussion - just like we did not in the past.

Comment: @Bill: I agree (at least, my first reaction is such) that generally multi-answering without comment isn't an issue, and initially I did not upvote this answer because of that. But after mulling it over, I realize the emphasis of the advice is to leave comment *when some sort of comment is needed*, and that's good advice. (I've since given +1)

Comment: @Bill: There's a big qualitative difference between lots of users each engaging in a little edgy behavior and a single poster engaging in a lot of edgy behavior.

Comment: @Hurkyl But there *are* other users who have multi-answered more than MK has. Also, given the votes here, it should be clear that not everyone agrees that multi-answering is "edgy behavior". As far as I know we have never had any case where it was even remotely clear that multi-answering was done for rep, so the whole matter seems to be much ado about nothing. No doubt that it *could* be abused. But it doesn't seem to have ever occurred here, not even once.

Comment: @Shog9 "Bill: regardless of how other instances have been received, it's indisputable that this case produced an unacceptable amount of confusion - both on the part of the asker, and the other readers."
I wonder why there were no complaints to Mariano who posted separate answers to a question.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105231/show-that-there-is-no-affine-transformation-that-takes-a-circle-to-a-hyperbola-i

Comment: @Shog9 "Bill: regardless of how other instances have been received, it's indisputable that this case produced an unacceptable amount of confusion - both on the part of the asker, and the other readers."
It's because some users have ill feelings toward me for some reasons which have nothing to do with the current subject.
The following is another example that they caused much "confusion" to a thread in which I participated.
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4936/voting-to-close-a-question-because-one-thinks-it-is-extremely-specialised

Comment: @Makoto: You were told many times before that your actions have cost your reputation (not the one in points, but rather the one you cannot quantify) as a member of this community. You cannot possibly be surprised that people still tend to be slightly more rigid with you than they would be with others. You have to work very hard to repair that broken reputation of yours, and by arguing with people constantly you're not helping yourself.

Comment: @Makato: considerably less confusion in the comments there (and no deleted comments).

Comment: @Makoto: The first thing you did after joining this site was to use it wrong. The next thing was to insist that you are using it right. Only after so many people gave up on trying you agreed to some mitigating solution, but you still insisted on doing things your way. Now say I come to visit your house, and I walk in with boots full of mud. I mess up your entire flat and leave muddy prints all over the sofa. You may be angry and I will insist this is just your opinion that I shouldn't do that. But will you invite me *again*? Especially if I won't apologize and promise to behave? I doubt that.

Comment: @Shog9 There were deleted comments and it was once closed. Now the thread is peaceful because I brought it up on meta and many people agreed and sympathized with me.

Comment: @Makato: on the question with Mariano's answers you linked to? No close votes, and all the comments are visible. On the question you answered, and linked to here? Yes, there was a lot of confusion, which calmed down after you explained yourself. Which is my point: when you encounter confusion, *explain what you're doing* - so many problems can be solved with just a bit of effort put into communication!

Comment: @Shog9 No. I was talking about the following link.
Just like it, I brought up the problem here to make it clear.
   

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4936/voting-to-close-a-question-because-one-thinks-it-i-extremely-specialised

Comment: @Makoto: Not sure how that's relevant, but yes you certainly did the right thing by bringing it up for discussion on meta.

Comment: @Shog9 It's relevant in that the threads were confused by people who have ill feelings toward me for some reasons which have nothing to do with the threads. You can find the same names in the both threads.

Comment: @Makoto: I find your name in both these threads. I also find Bill's name in both these threads. I also find Hurkyl and my name. I also find Michael Greinecker's name as well Mariano participated there and was mentioned in this thread, so his name appears in both threads. Could you clarify who are the members of the secret "Anti MK" society?

Comment: @Makoto: Be careful about treating all negative feedback as evidence of some sort of witch-hunt though; I hardly think everyone involved here sits around waiting for you to do something so they can pounce on you. Yeah, there are probably folks who take an unnecessarily dim view of your efforts, but there are just as surely folks who simply care about the site and its community and wish to see problems resolved.

Comment: @Shog9 How do you explain the asymmetry between the Mariano's case and mine?

Comment: @Makoto: the simplest explanation is that he wrote answers that were clear to the asker.

Comment: What does it have to do with complaints against separate answers?

Comment: @Makoto: If the first purpose of answering is to help the asker, then multiple helpful answers are not a bad thing. But if the asker struggles to understand one answer, another answer which also confuses him does not improve matters. Remember your comment about the pedagogical value of answers which present alternate solutions? This is predicated on the student understanding the solutions presented; without that, they might as well be noise. More noise is never an improvement.

Comment: @Makoto: I looked at a thread where Mariano posted many answers. My initial impression was rather negative. The difference now between my response to his and my response to yours is that Mariano has enough content that it would take a fair bit of effort to make up my mind how I really feel about it, and do not expect any utility from doing so. Your answers, OTOH, were short, sparse, and similar, and would have made sense as a single answer or even just one or more comments, and they came from a poster who has a long history of pushing the boundaries of what people consider acceptable behavior.

Answer (score 15):

When answers legitimately take different approaches, separate answers are usually better since they each come with different direct links and comments sections.

Answer (score 14):

One reason for preferring a single answer is given when you try to add another answer, which suggests *refining* and *improving* an existing answer.

The answers you gave are not especially distinct from one another. By combining them into a single answer, the relationships between them can be seen implicitly through juxtaposition -- or even better, it could be explained *explicitly*. The combined answer could easily be much more illuminating than three individual answers.

I imagine that the answers aren't especially distinct aggravated the negative reaction to multi-answering.

Comment: "The answers you gave are not especially distinct from one another."

(1) is based on the fundametal theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.
(2) is based on the theory of vector spaces over a finite field.
(3) is based on the Cauchy's theorem. This proof also can be applied to a non-abelian finite group all of whose elements have a prime power orders.
How come those are not especially distinct from one another?

Comment: At the highest level, the theory of vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is identical with the theory of abelian groups with exponent $p$.

--- In the situation of the post, the structure theorem for f.g. Abelian groups is the same thing as the theorem that finite-dimensional vector spaces have a basis.

--- In fact, you could swap the first sentences of (1) and (2) and still have answers at the same level of rigor as the originals. 

--- Answers (1) and (3) are both just "every element has order $p$". They only look different because of the (unnecessary) argument surrounding them.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups has nothing to do with the theory of vector spaces over a finite prime field. (1) is based on the former and (2) is based on the latter.

Answer (score 11):

There are various *honorable* reasons that one may have for posting more than one answer to a question. For example, often I am interested in judging how well-known various approaches are, so that I can use that feedback to revise my teaching methodology. This is more difficult to do if one places multiple answers in one post since then it is not clear which particular answer the votes and comments target (which, by the way, is a *huge* problem with votes on multiple-answers on *meta*).

For a concrete example, I explicitly chose *not* to place the well-known degree-based approach into my [answer on why polynomial rings are not fields,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523/242) because I sought to determine what sort of response the given *universal* approach would receive. The surprisingly large number of votes it received (along with the tone of the comments) helped provide further evidence to confirm my suspicion that many algebra textbooks do not effectively teach such universal ideas.

It is important to keep in mind that - in this way - the site provides useful feedback to teachers. Having *sharp modular boundaries* between *logically independent answers* serves to optimize the value of such feedback. This allows teachers to *learn* as well as teach, which provides much further motivation for teachers to participate. And, of course, the more teachers we have participating, the more the site will prosper.

Another reason for posting multiple answers is to draw modular boundaries between knowledge levels. Sometimes I post answers that include both elementary and advanced perspectives on topics. These combined posts often receive fewer votes than if I separate the answer into an elementary post and an advanced post. Probably this is because the advanced parts scare away those with no knowledge of the advanced topics, so they stop reading -  mistakenly believing that the *entire* post is too advanced.

Similarly, students may have honorable reasons for posting multiple answers in separate posts. For example, a student with two answers may be confident of the first, but may have doubts about the second answer. Thus it makes sense to post the second answer separately, so that feedback on it can be appropriately isolated. Otherwise, if both answers were combined into one post and the second answer had problems, then the combined answer might receive a mix of upvotes and downvotes, which might relay false impressions about the first answer, e.g. misleading readers into thinking that the first answer also has problems. Further, the first answer might not get elevated to the proper level of exposure, possibly leaving an inferior answer to be the highest-voted.

Generally, readers may desire to upvote some answers and downvote others, which is not possible if they are all combined into one answer.

---

Finally, one  tangential point is worth emphasis. Before one leaps towards accusations such as "reputation farming" etc, it is important to keep in mind that not everyone pays attention to reputation, so it may not even occur to some folks that posting multiple answers might be viewed that way. Indeed, some of us are here simply to share our knowledge of mathematics, and have been doing so for years in other forums (e.g. usenet newsgroups) where reputation plays no role. Please try to keep in mind the diversity of our community before jumping to possibly unfounded conclusions about such matters.

Comment: There are also some people who do not care about money. Should we allow people who don't care about money to get free money as long as they need? No. It is true that some users don't care about reputation, but others can. I would hate to think that we should give a precedent case of posting multiple answers *just because* someone doesn't care about reputation (or so they say). I do agree that there *are* reasons for posting several answers, though. I haven't looked at the specified question, so I cannot tell about this one, though.

Comment: That analogy is not appropriate. Multiple independent answers don't get free upvotes. Each answer still has to earn its own upvotes (or downvotes). The point of my *tangential* remark is to encourage others to show some empathy when attempting to understand the motivations of others. Some of our users are not motivated at all by the rep game, and it is essential to keep that in mind when evaluating such matters.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I support posting multiple answers.  Why wouldn't we?  It's your personal preference not to?  So, it's my personal preference to.

Comment: @Graphth: I **really** don't see the relevance of your comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Then don't upvote it.

Comment: @Graphth: I didn't vote it... If anything I would have flagged it as "too chatty" and irrelevant. I'm just retorting your irrelevance with mine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't really understand the relevance of yours.  Bill is saying there are reasons to do separate answers.  You reply and say we shouldn't believe any one who says they are not in it for reputation.  If people who don't care about money do work to deserve the money, then who cares if they get it?  They did the work to deserve it.  Why are we so concerned with people getting reputation?  It's not like any one is gaming the system and ending up as one of the top users on here because of it.  They may game the system and end up with an extra hundred reputation per month.

Comment: @Graphth: No, I am pointing out that the tangential point is not **that** tangential. There **are** people on this site who would game the system whenever they could. For badges, for reputation, for whatever. We should be careful in the precedents we set to allow. The fact that Bill is sitting so high on the shoulders of the giants and does not care about reputation, and whether or not MK is also careless for reputation, does not mean that we should immediately assume that whoever *does post several answers* is not gaming the system.

Comment: @Graphth More generally, I think that the problem of unfounded accusations based on misunderstandings is a problem much more deserving of attention than multiple-answer rep farming (which, if it even exists, is probably infinitesimal). Such accusations, whether they are about homework cheating, rep farming etc, are a major source of tension on the site.

Comment: @Graphth: If anything, then your comment is truly irrelevant. You add nothing to the discussion, except to point out that you support Bill's approach. Bravo, here's a round of applause. *clap clap clap*. Upvote his answer, there is no need to add useless comments. Bill should know how quickly comments degenerate to cynical and irrelevant discussions, and I'm sure he wouldn't appreciate such discussion here on his answer.

Comment: @Asaf: the comparison between rep and money only goes so far... arguably not far at all. Rep is almost worthless, more so as it accumulates (for those with no interest in mod tools or whatever the privileges are at the upper level). Furthermore...

Comment: @TheChaz: Shall I compare it to drugs, then? Reputation is a driving force, regardless what anyone says. This is why there is so many cries when people are getting downvoted, and this is why people feel good when they are getting upvoted.

Comment: @Asaf But that's precisely my point - one should not make *presumptions* without full understanding of *all* of the possible motivations for posting multiple answers.

Comment: (... Never mind. I will hold my tongue/fingers/whatever)

Comment: @Bill: And my point is that the fact people *do* game the system means that there is a reason for rules, and there is a reason to avoid making precedents. You're a master in the art of "slippery slope" arguments, I'm sure you see my point.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree that we don't need to assume anyone doing this does NOT care about reputation.  And, I agree that many probably do.  I'm just saying, if we're trying to make a decision on something, it seems like one of the least important reasons to use.  Again, if someone really does game the system on something like this, it's not like they're going to vault themselves to be a top user.  They might add some reputation but not all that much.  Other people ask stupid questions and get 200 upvotes, 3 gold badges, and 800 reputation.  Do we have a rule against that?

Comment: @Asaf You wrote: "Reputation is a driving force, regardless what anyone says..." That may be true for you, but you cannot speak for others. Some of our most prolific contributors  participated in sci.math for years/decades without any rep motivation whatsoever (there is no rep capability in usenet newgroups). I suspect that, like I, most of those folks are little-motivated by rep. Instead, they are surely primarily motivated by *teaching.*

Comment: @Bill: Sheesh, you are such a condescending person. It is impossible to speak with you without getting angry. It is a tangential point, but I feel that you are impossible to reason, discuss or argue with. You have set your mind and *nothing* can change your opinion. I feel ashamed to have a person like you to hold *any* power within this site. I am not going to reply to your comments again here, or elsewhere.

Comment: @Graphth: No. I also weep for the Batman question and the others. I also feel that sometimes newcomers which asked such questions try to replicate the "success". It's a shame. Yes. I can't stop people from voting. I can try and consolidate a mass opinion **against** gaming the system, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd rather have two sufficiently different answers neatly organized as two separate posts.  That's more important to me than worrying about whether or not someone is gaming the system.  So, if it's borderline, I'd rather someone neatly organize things than worry about whether or not some users are going to accuse them of rep farming.  That is, a user shouldn't have to think "Hmm, are people going to think I'm gaming the system if I do this" if they honestly aren't.  And, other users should give the benefit of the doubt so that honest people don't worry about this.

Comment: @Asaf I think you misinterpreted something above, possibly my remark about "That may be true for you... " which was intended to mean that while you may believe that to be true, you cannot possibly know without speaking to others. But that's yet another example of folks jumping to conclusions and presuming bad intentions when none were intended. That is far too often the source of unneeded tension. If folks would only give other members the benefit of the doubt then most of the tension on MSE would quickly evaporate.

Comment: @Bill: I could just as easily say that a lot of tension would vanish if people stopped countering valid issues with platitudes. Problematic behavior done with good intentions is still problematic behavior. If you really want to give benefit of doubt, then assume Asaf's intent is to *actually worry about problems* rather than to be misanthropic or whatever else you are assuming, and react accordingly.

Comment: @Hurkyl As should be clear by now, not everyone agrees that posting multiple independent answers is "problematic behavior". Your final sentence makes no sense. To understand the context is it essential to read the *entire* comment thread.

Comment: @Bill: Non-problematic behavior is non-problematic. I agree that there are differences in opinion. The part I find insulting is the implication that we shouldn't even contemplate whether behavior is problematic, because some people behave that way with good intentions. Empathy for people who engage in (possibly) problematic behavior is fine -- but don't let that cloud your judgment of the behavior. Similarly, you should have empathy for people who are actually out there trying to judge things fairly; your tangential remark is rather patronizing, and it suggests the aforementioned insult.

Comment: @Hurkyl Your inference is one *giant unfounded leap*! Some users argued that there are good reasons to allow multiple answers. How do you go from that to claiming that they believe "we shouldn't even contemplate whether behavior is problematic, because some people behave that way with good intentions"? Nobody said (or implied) that. That strawman is your own creation. If you deem your strawman to be "insulting" then the fix is easy: stop creating strawmen! They don't lend to constructive arguments. Similarly, the rest of what you say also does not apply to anything anyone has said here.

Comment: @Hurkyl I don't agree that the tangential remark is "patronizing." Its purpose it to help others understand the diverse viewpoints in our community. Without being aware of such, someone who makes false rep farming accusations might easily alienate users who post multiple-answers with honorable intentions, e.g. (newly-joined) teachers. Increasing awareness of these diverse viewpoints will arm users with the information needed to give others the benefit of the doubt (when it is deserved), which goes a long way towards avoiding friction in the community.

Comment: @Bill: And I'm concerned about alienating users who would speak out with *honorable intentions* about perceived problems. Just as you (rightly) point out that such people can cause harm if they act carelessly, I assert that you are causing harm by being similarly careless (if I give you the benefit of the doubt, anyways). While these implications may not have been in your *intent*, they are present in your *words*, and it is your *words* that are the content of your answer....

Comment: .... Additionally, special care is needed for such comments, because of how commonly they are used to **bully** those who would offer objections or criticism. A lot of ill feelings arise when people are led to believe their opinions and arguments are being drowned out -- or even *vilified* -- by gratuitous warm and fuzzy sentiments.

Comment: To see how your words are misinterpreted, pay attention to your remark. "Before one leaps towards accusations" -- note the choice of words with negative connotations. "important to keep in mind <foo>". Why is it important to keep it in mind? The most obvious interpretation is that <foo> is intended as a reason why one should not put forth an opinion. Your final sentence readily reinforces this interpretation, connecting "diversity of our community" with "jumping to possibly unfounded conclusions", a rather strongly negative description of voicing opinions on the topic.

Comment: @Hurkyl Yet more strawman arguments. I have no interest in engaging in such.

Comment: There are various good, useful, or honorable reasons to do many things. Was that true in this case? If so, what could MK do to make them more apparent in the future, and thereby avoid the problems he encountered? If not, what should he have done instead? This is a good answer for the hypothetical case of multiple answers, but I think what @Hurkyl is getting at is: do these *generalities* apply to the *specific* case raised in the question?

Comment: @Shog9 Providing different approaches to a problem is a pedagogically good thing to do.

Comment: @BillDubuque Your internet experience doesn't seem to translate to the ability to state your opinion in a way that does not offend or alienate others. The problem is exacerbated by you having a history of actually insulting other users outright.

Comment: @Michael Don't believe the strawmen. Let's please get this thread back on topic.

Comment: @Bill There is no insult among you comments *here*, but very bad wording. "Apparently, That may be true for you, but you cannot speak for others." begs to be read as Asaf being a rep-w&/%e. The remark "I suspect that, like I, most of those folks are little-motivated by rep. Instead, they are surely primarily motivated by teaching." can allude to Asaf not caring about teaching. Of course, one does not have to interpret things this way, but internet experience should teach you how to phrase things better.

Comment: @Michael Please see above: I already noticed that sentence may have been misinterpreted, and I explained what was meant. I am one of the most prolific writers on meta. With such volume there is bound to be some passages with ambiguity. The best I can do is clarify them when they are brought to my attention.  The second quoted sentence certainly does *not* make any "allusions about Asaf" (or anyone *in particular*). Apparently some readers understood the comment fine (and agreed) since it is currently the highest-voted comment above.

Comment: @Makato: it *can* be a good thing. I'm not convinced that *in this case* it was: given the number of (now-deleted) comments on your answers, it seems like you may have simply caused more confusion in the student. When your answers prompt *multiple* requests for clarification, it can be a pretty good sign you missed the mark when evaluating the asker's skill level - and a good time for some clarifying edits.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not claiming each of my answers is good enough for the OP.
I'm just saying it is a pedagogically good thing to provide different approaches to a problem.
Even if the OP doesn't understand them now, he may be able to understand them someday.
I'm not talking about the OP only.
I'm sure there are users who understand my answers and learn something from them.

Comment: @Makoto: If your answers are "pedagogical" why are there no explanations? Why are the answers concise and lack actual explanations? If the answers are for *future* readers (including the future OP) how would voting help you establish any reasonable input over which approach is preferable?

Comment: @Makoto: Your comment is off topic. This meta topic isn't about whether people should provide different approaches to a problem. This meta topic is about if and when a person providing different approaches should put them in a single answer.

Comment: @Hurkyl Makoto's comment is certainly on-topic, in fact it is much more on-topic than many of the other comments in this meandering comment thread, which has degenerated into highly tangential strawman arguments, far from the main issues at hand.

Comment: @Bill: Do you seriously believe that anybody in this thread has argued that it is not helpful to present multiple approaches to a problem?!?!?! Or have said anything else that would actually be addressed by advocating that questioners be shown multiple approaches? I harp on it because it looks like yet another instance of Makoto's oblivious act where he continually ignores the actual criticisms and instead discusses other aspects of a situation. (it might not be an act, but it's becoming increasingly implausible that he's acting in good faith)

Answer (score 6):

**Usual cases**

There is nothing wrong with giving multiple answers, as long as they are sufficiently different. However, it is customary to give them all in the same post, headed by a **bold title** and separated by a line `***`.

---

**Exceptional cases**

If one of the answers is very long, it might be necessary to make an additional post, but that is a very exceptional case.

Comment: What about posting an answer to a question which someone else already answered?
There is nothing wrong with doing so, as long as they are sufficiently different?

Comment: Absolutely not. As long as they don't duplicate each other; the more, the merrier!

Comment: I prefer separate answers in separate posts.

Comment: @robjohn Even if he is reputation farming?

Comment: @MakotoKato: I would not call a good answer for a question, whether or not someone else has already answered, reputation farming.

Comment: @robjohn Please explain why you demand sufficient differences in multiple answers by a user while you don't care about it with an answer to a question which someone already answered.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Not all social behavior can be quantified into a well-defined list of laws. In fact, most of it can't. Human beings are just this sort of wonderful creature that develop a big brain exactly for this purpose: to understand what is the community norm without having a flowchart which defines completely everything. Your incessant requests for "definitions" are almost always impossible to counter without shrugging and giving up (as many people do, if you look at the comment histories of your various threads).

Comment: @MakotoKato: I thought it had already been decided that the answers considered, whether from a single or multiple users, were "sufficiently different".

Comment: @robjohn I think I misunderstood you. I'd like to withdraw my last comment. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Could you give us some supporting evidences of your claim that it is customary to give them all in the same post?

Comment: @MakotoKato: I would have to spend more than I have right now to find more, but [here is one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/234828)

Comment: @robjohn Here is an example of multiple separate answers by the same user. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105231/show-that-there-is-no-affine-transformation-that-takes-a-circle-to-a-hyperbola-i

Comment: @MakotoKato: I would consider the approach of those answers suffuciently different.  Algebra, algebraic geometry, and two geometry (the two geometry might be a bit close, both using localization properties of invertible affine maps). In any case, I don't get the impression that Mariano was reputation farming.

Comment: @robjohn I just picked it up as an example of multiple separate answers by the same user in contrast with your claim that it is customary to post them in a single post.

Comment: @Makoto: Are you capable of seeing the difference between three *long* answers and three *two lines* answers? (Hint: it's the length of the answers)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you mean that if they are about 10 lines each, it's OK?

Comment: @MakotoKato: I would say that it is a combination of size and uniqueness, and it is hard to put a quantitative cutoff on things like uniqueness.

Comment: Are you implying that you think my answers are not sufficiently different?

Comment: @MakotoKato: I have only spoken in general, except where I have commented on specific examples of Mariano's and mine. I have made no comment on your answers.

Comment: I'd like to know what you think about my answers.

Comment: Since I did not vote on your answers, that would be off topic here.

Answer (score 3):

One reason we sometimes see multiple answers to the same question is some doubt as to the mathematical knowledge or experience of the person who has asked the question.

In such cases I think it is of general benefit to the person who has asked the question - and to future explorers of the site - to have the links between levels indicated.

My oldest daughter (aged 15) said to me yesterday - when I ask you about homework you often go off onto things I haven't learnt yet, and which I don't quite understand - but then when my teacher deals with them in class, I do get them, and my classmates don't. She was pondering why that was, and I was thinking - it's how I learned mathematics - from my dad.

This is a great site for sensing the direction of travel and the challenges ahead.

Comment: That is one of the reasons that I mentioned in the fifth paragraph of my answer. I wholeheartedly agree about links. I've probably posted almost as many links as answers (a couple thousand), since I believe that showing the diverse and beautiful interconnections  in the mathematical web is one of the great pedagogical values that this site has to offer vs. other learning resources (e.g. paper textbooks, which are limited by linear organization).

Answer (score -6):

The issue here is with reputation farming. Therefore, if you wish to post multiple answers and do not wish to suffer any hopstilities from anyone there is a simple solution.

> Have one "main" answer. Make the rest community wikis.

If you are not simply after reputation then you should have no issues with this, and noone can criticise you for it. Simples!

Comment: I disagree: if answers are interesting and sufficiently different, I see no problem with getting reputation for both of them; if answers are not sufficiently different they shouldn't be separate CW or not.

Comment: How is it reasonable to bump a year and a half old cesspool just for this? (Also, congrats on the recent upgrade in status!)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! I thought it was reasonable because noone had suggested this (also, Makoto brought up the linked-to main question elsewhere, so it is vaguely topical). To clarify my answer a bit: if someone posts an answer in the comments but the question remains unanswered for a while then I would happily paraphrase the comment into an answer and, if I had nothing more to add, make my answer a community wiki. I see no difference here - *if* you are not rep hungry *and* you do not wish to be seen as rep hungry *but* you still want to post multiple answers *then* this is the only solution

Comment: I think that the point (in retrospect), was not reputation farming, as much as lack of acceptance of any negative criticism. Shog9's answer really sums up everything, and to the 10k users, there's a deleted answer with some comments which also make an excellent addition to that. But I really have no intention to be dragged into the soon-to-come nonsense by some of the meta flamethrowers, and this will conclude my remarks here for the time being. (Congrats again on the Ph.D., I hear it's like a "black belt in mathematics".)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree with Shog's answer, and I agree with his interpretation of the question. *However*, the other 5 answers (+mine) address the question in the title. I interpreted the events as there being two questions, with shog having the definitive answer to the underlying one and with the other answers addressing the more interesting question which is actually relevant to other people. (The only problem with a PhD is that you have to start at the bottom again. Yes, it is like a black-belt, but you are a [0-dan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_rank) black belt...)

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/296737/242) is a question with **seven** answers from a moderator. Strangely, no one had any problems with that, but they did when MK posted 3 answers. Bias?  I think so.